# How to handle processing real-time events that fire before processing of previous event is complete (C#)

Tags: c#, events, real-time, buffering

Suppose we have a listener to a real-time event that executes some block of code upon the event being triggered.

for our discussion lets say we have a MyTime class, that has a member currentTime.

we have set it up so that whenever the computer clock changes, the currentTime is set to the value of current time.
We've implemented the property changed INotifyPropertyChanged interface for our currentTime object:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


       public string currentTime
            {
                get { return _currentTime; }
                set { _currentTime= value; this.NotifyPropertyChanged("currentTime"); } 
             }


    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {

    if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

    }
```

Some other class, say ProcessTime is listening to this event:

```
TimeChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(PropertyChanged};
```

and it has a function that will execute something:

```
public void TimeChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{

// Process lots of calculations

}
```

Since our computer clock changes all the time, it will keep firing the event.
In my understanding, once the first time change occurs, we will execute the TimeChanged block. While we are executing, we will keep getting more and more notifications and processing them as fast as we can, creating a long queue of events still to be processed.

The problem is that after we process the first time change and move on to the next time change, the "real time" is already far ahead, and whatever we are calculating we are calculating for something that happened in the past.

What we would like to do is to ignore all new events until we finish our original processing, and only then start listening again for the event.

Setting up multiple threads is not an option as it doesn't address the issue, and we do not want to process every time change, only those when our resources have been freed up.

Obviously I've used the time change and the above code as a demonstrative example, but it demonstrates concisely and adequately (IMHO) what we are trying to accomplish here.

I would imagine to use some kind of buffer, but my knowledge here is very very limited.
Thanks

Thanks for all the answers so far. Will start on implementing it. Will try to document successes / failures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first the event in question is not being called asynchronously.  So Unless you're setting the time on constantly changing threads, the call to set the time won't come back and you won't set it again until all of the events have handled it.  If you want to prevent this problem, you need to move event handling to a different thread.

Ultimately the complexity of the situation and exactly how real-time you want to be can dictate the ultimate answer to this.  But, assuming you want something that's fairly robust for a relatively few number of threads (let's say a dozen), here's roughly how I'd go about doing this.

```
private var _Callbacks = new List<PropertyChangedEventHandler>();

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
{
    add
    {
        lock(_Callbacks)
            _Callbacks.Add(value);

        Thread Worker = new Thread(PollTime);
        Worker.Background = true;
        Worker.Start(value);
    }
    remove
    {
        lock(_Callbacks)
            _Callbacks.Remove(value);
    }
}

private void PollTime(object callback)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler c = (PropertyChangedEventHandler)callback;
    string LastReported = null;

    while(true)
    {
        lock(_Callbacks)
            if (!_Callbacks.Contains(c))
                return;

        if (LastReported != _currentTime)
        {
            LastReported = _currentTime;
            c(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
        else
            Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}

public string currentTime
{
    get { return _currentTime; }
    set { _currentTime= value; } 
}
```

With that you get thread safety on your events (in case someone tries to subscribe/unsubscribe from them at an inopportune time), and each subscriber gets it's own thread to handle callbacks.  The subscribers won't get all the same events, but they will all be notified when the time changes.  Slower ones just won't get as many events because they'll lose some of the intermediate values.  This won't notify if the time is reset with no change, but I don't see that as much of a loss.  You may see problems if values alternate within a limited set, but with time that's not a problem.

For more reading on delegates, events and how they work, there's a very long, but very good piece at http://www.sellsbrothers.com/writing/delegates.htm

Comment: If you start reporting the value in the event, use `LastReported` to avoid thread concurrency issues.  Also it's worth pointing out that if your updates are bursty, every subscriber will get the last value that's pushed out (assuming that they don't take so long that they overlap the next burst)

Answer (score 2):

This would be my approach.

1. Do not let the consumer block the producer's event thread.
2. Create a lightweight "critical section" (basically an atomic condition variable) so that only one invocation of a consumer handler can be active at a given time.

Here is a complete example which implements this logic.  There is an `EventProducer` and an `EventConsumer`.  They can be configured to be faster or slower than each other as needed.  The event producer creates a background thread to raise events. The `EventConsumer` uses a custom `CriticalSectionSlim` class with a simple `TryEnter`/`Exit` pattern to avoid simultaneous invocations of the handling code. It also posts the handling code to the thread pool using the default behavior of the .NET 4.0 `Task` class. If an exception occurs, it is rethrown from the main handler thread on the next invocation.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

internal sealed class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (EventProducer producer = new EventProducer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250.0d)))
        using (EventConsumer consumer = new EventConsumer(producer, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0d)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to stop.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    }

    private static class ConsoleLogger
    {
        public static void WriteLine(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "[{0}]({1}) {2}",
                DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                message);
        }
    }

    private sealed class EventConsumer : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly CriticalSectionSlim criticalSection;
        private readonly EventProducer producer;
        private readonly TimeSpan processingTime;

        private Task currentTask;

        public EventConsumer(EventProducer producer, TimeSpan processingTime)
        {
            if (producer == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("producer");
            }

            if (processingTime < TimeSpan.Zero)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("processingTime");
            }

            this.processingTime = processingTime;
            this.criticalSection = new CriticalSectionSlim();
            this.producer = producer;
            this.producer.SomethingHappened += this.OnSomethingHappened;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        private void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                this.producer.SomethingHappened -= this.OnSomethingHappened;
            }
        }

        private void OnSomethingHappened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.criticalSection.TryEnter())
            {
                try
                {
                    this.StartTask();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    this.criticalSection.Exit();
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        private void StartTask()
        {
            if (this.currentTask != null)
            {
                this.currentTask.Wait();
            }

            this.currentTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(this.OnSomethingHappenedTask);
        }

        private void OnSomethingHappenedTask()
        {
            try
            {
                this.OnSomethingHappenedImpl();
            }
            finally
            {
                this.criticalSection.Exit();
            }
        }

        private void OnSomethingHappenedImpl()
        {
            ConsoleLogger.WriteLine("BEGIN: Consumer processing.");
            Thread.CurrentThread.Join(this.processingTime);
            ConsoleLogger.WriteLine("END:   Consumer processing.");
        }
    }

    private sealed class EventProducer : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly TimeSpan timeBetweenEvents;
        private readonly Thread thread;
        private volatile bool shouldStop;

        public EventProducer(TimeSpan timeBetweenEvents)
        {
            if (timeBetweenEvents < TimeSpan.Zero)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("timeBetweenEvents");
            }

            this.timeBetweenEvents = timeBetweenEvents;
            this.thread = new Thread(this.Run);
            this.thread.Start();
        }

        public event EventHandler SomethingHappened;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        private void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                this.shouldStop = true;
                this.thread.Join();
            }
        }

        private void Run()
        {
            while (!shouldStop)
            {
                this.RaiseEvent();
                Thread.CurrentThread.Join(this.timeBetweenEvents);
            }
        }

        private void RaiseEvent()
        {
            EventHandler handler = this.SomethingHappened;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                ConsoleLogger.WriteLine("Producer is raising event.");
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    private sealed class CriticalSectionSlim
    {
        private int active;

        public CriticalSectionSlim()
        {
        }

        public bool TryEnter()
        {
            return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this.active, 1, 0) == 0;
        }

        public void Exit()
        {
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.active, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do something like this

as soon as you receive the event, unregister the event or in other words stop listening to event anymore.

Once you are done with your event processing start listening to event again by re-registering to event

```
public void TimeChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{

//un register
TimeChanged -= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(PropertyChanged};

// Process lots of calculations

//re-register
TimeChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(PropertyChanged};

}
```

Comment: You are messing with a collection by registering/unregistering repeatedly and that may actually break the event calling code.

Comment: @Haris Hasan In the specific case we are not worried about a collection, just a particular item. Would that be problematic? If so, ideas how to avoid?
Follow-up to this: what do you think is the time hit on registering/unregistering? The idea would be to "miss" as few events  as possible

Comment: I can't think of any reason which can cause problem in that case. You are already missing few events during processing I don't think you will major numbers of events just because you are re-registering for the event

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that all scheduled tasks be placed in a queue ordered by process time (DateTime). The time event (tick) only needs to check the if the task at the head of the queue is 'pending'. That is if its time to process has been reached or passed. Then that task is removed from the queue, given the current time, and executed.

The task notifies the task queue when it has finished by a call back given in the execute method (that presumably also took current time). The task queue will not execute any other tasks while a task is executing. When a task notifies completion the task queue will immediately check if the task, if any, at the head of the queue is pending and so on.

Now a nice refinement that can be done here when u have time ordered task queue is that instead of periodic ticks you set a timer to fire (or one time changed listener) when it is time to execute the task at the head of the queue as you always know the time to next event. No need to multiple listeners and one controller for how many are executing, etc.

```
interface ITask
{
    void Execute(ITaskCallBack callBack, DateTime currentTime);
}

interface ITaskCallBack
{
    void OnCompleted(ITask task); // The task parameter is needed for concurrency
}
```

Whenever a task is added or deleted the time to next event is updated.

*Important:* If you add a new task that happens to wants to execute at the same time as an existing task you should add it after all tasks for the same time. This avoids child tasks hogging the scheduler.

The timed queue is your task scheduler/controller. You can make it single threaded or multi threaded as you like. Although I do not see much point in multi threading unless your using multiple processors.

```
interface ITaskScheduler
{
    void Add(ITask task, DateTime executeTime);
    void Remove(ITask);
}
```

Another nice spin off here is that the scheduler knows the time scheduled and the time actually started. Hence you have valuable diagnostic for delayed tasks or latencies due to loading. Important if you system needs to performance deterministic.

Hope this makes sense and is useful.

Best regards